# Asking user to input a file from their computer

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

New python 2.7 user. I just started learning about dictionaries and asking the user for input so I can make a little code to practice manipulating dictionaries such as simple math computations.

I am able to ask a user to input something manually such as :

```
 fav_numbs = (raw_input("What is your favorite car and color?: "))
```

I am wanting to get the user's information in a dictionary. Instead of asking the user to manually type in their favorite cars and colors of that car, I want them to import their own file from their computer. So far, I have came up with:

```
 fav_cars = raw_input('Enter file name that contains your favorite cars and color. The file must have the first column as favorite cars and a second column includes your favorite color of that particular car: ')
 myfile = open(fav_cars, 'r')
```

I am assuming the user can just put in the file name the same way as one can input a file into their python code? I know that if the python file and the file being imported are in the same folder, all that is needed is the file name.

My next set of code includes:

```
 if __name__ == "__main__":
 Testfilename = '????'   #this is what I do not know what to put in my code!
 fav_cars_dict = {}
 path = open(Testfilename)
```

Based on when I want to input a file into my code myself, I would just put the file name where I have question marks above. What do I put here, if I do not know the name of the file the user will be putting in? I did not include the code after this, but will if it is needed to help the problem. I just proceeded to convert the file to a dictionary using for-loops by filling in the question marks with a file that has 10 sets of numbers in one column that I created.

Comment: maybe you are looking for `None`

Comment: No, that does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have an input argument, use sys python library. Add to a file

```
import sys
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
   test_dir_name = os.getcwd()  # Current directory
   test_file_name = sys.argv[1]  # Get the first input argument 
   path = open(os.path.join(test_dir_name, test_file_name))
```

If the above file is named PythonDictReader.py, you can execute using

```
python PythonDictReader.py file_name
```

Comment: I tried this using the file name from my computer that is stored in the same folder as the python file. The error code I got is : Testfilename = sys.argv[1]  # Get the first input argument

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: How did you execute the code? Note the variable name change in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is run on the command line, you'll want to use `argparse` to get the file path from the user, instead of `raw_input`. But either way, you shouldn't worry about where the user is importing the file from. Files specified by relative and absolute path are practically handled the same way. So your "???" would still be fav_cars. If you're really curious, os.path.abspath(*path*) will give you the absolute path for any valid path the user enters.

Comment: I have never heard or used argparse before. I have done my simple codes using raw_input. Will I not be able to use raw_input to call for a file from the user?